# This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms while caching

Tags: fips

We have created a web app that caches a drop down list of states and only recaches once a week.  I disabled FIPS in the registry and cannot find any information on what to do about this issue.

Everytime I run the app I get a FIPS error despite FIPS being disabled.

edit: I have since added this line in the dev.exe.config file

The issue still remains. Anyone know how I am getting a FIPS error when it should not know fips exists. (I have restarted my comp many times hoping to solve this issue as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a seriously difficult problem to research. If you are having issues even after doing what I stated above this is how you can solve it. (assuming you can turn FIPS compliance off on your machine.) Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa 
In this folder you should see FipsAlgorithmPolicy. DELETE this registry entry and restart. If you system is dual encrypted you cannot run any form of caching in .net.

Here is the documentation I found on this issue.
https://getsatisfaction.com/web_active_directory/topics/why_do_i_get_a_parser_error_message_about_windows_platform_fips

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/07/20/parser-error-message-this-implementation-is-not-part-of-the-windows-platform-fips-validated-cryptographic-algorithms-when-net-page-has-debug-true.aspx

http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2009/07/20/parser-error-message-this-implementation-is-not-part-of-the-windows-platform-fips-validated-cryptographic-algorithms-when-net-page-has-debug-true.aspx

Comment: Yeah, when people make the change through the registry (they shouldn't) instead of through the policy this happens. I hate when people implement Retina fixes, becuase it instructs them to make all of them through registry which is INCORRECT! Always make the changes through the Policy editor!!